# Сделать, чтобы при вводе имени запрос не был чувствителен к регистру

Tags: oracle, php

Хочу задать вопрос, чтобы при вводе имени запрос не был чувствителен к регистру. То есть он мог написать "кончита", "Кончита", "КоНчИтА" и нашлось бы одно "Кончита" (в базе насколько я понял все пишется с заглавной). В принципе можно сильно и не усложнять, просто менять строчные буквы в начале на заглавные, ну и (защита от дурака) - заглавные в слове на строчные, чтобы запрос выглядел where name = 'Кончита'. Как это проще сделать - средствами пхп проверять что ввел пользователь или запрос в оракл передать какой нить красивый.

Comment: решается с помощью пхп

       $str = mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHERE LOWER(`name`) = LOWER('КоНчИтА')

Comment: но мне то нужно чтобы первая была заглавная

Comment: function check($str){

    return 
strtoupper($str[0]).strtolower(substr($str,1,strlen($str)));

}


echo check("pRiVet");
Будет "Privet",
можно и в запрос подставить 
WHERE name = 'check("pRiVet")'